# what should be my p_row_selector value for apex_data_parser.parse?

Tags: xml-parsing, oracle-apex

I am trying to parse an XML file on APEX18

XML structure is like this:

```html
<Document>
  <group_1>
    <group_1_1>
      <MsgId>x</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2023-05-01T16:20:06.770+00:00</CreDtTm>
      <MsgPgntn>
        <PgNb>1</PgNb>
        <LastPgInd>richtig</LastPgInd>
      </MsgPgntn>
    </group_1_1>
    <group_1_2>
      <Id>36</Id>
      <Acct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>xxx</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
        <Ownr>
          <Id>
            <OrgId>
              <AnyBIC>yyy</AnyBIC>
            </OrgId>
          </Id>
        </Ownr>
      </Acct>
      <Bal>
        <Tp>
          <CdOrPrtry>
            <Cd>aaa</Cd>
          </CdOrPrtry>
        </Tp>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">0.00</Amt>
        <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
        <Dt>
          <Dt>2023-01-01</Dt>
        </Dt>
      </Bal>
      <Bal>
        <Tp>
          <CdOrPrtry>
            <Cd>bbb</Cd>
          </CdOrPrtry>
        </Tp>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">0.00</Amt>
        <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
        <Dt>
          <Dt>2023-01-02</Dt>
        </Dt>
      </Bal>
    </group_1_2>
  </group_1>
</Document>
```

I upload this file via :P1_NEW (file browser) item, then try to select it with below query

```
select line_number, col001, col002, col003, col004, col005
  from apex_application_temp_files x, 
       table(apex_data_parser.parse(
                  p_content                     => x.blob_content,
                  p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
                  p_row_selector                => '/Document/group_1/group_1_2',                  
                  p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                  p_file_name                   => x.filename)) y
 where x.name = :P1_NEW
```

and this is what I'm getting as result

[image]

however, I am expecting to see all the sub-tags within their parents as seperate columns. Is it futile? if it can be done, how can I set my row selector to get (for this sample) Id, Acct, Ownr, Bal... values in different columns at once?

Comment: I would think that, just like for json parsing you can only parse at one level and not get nested attributes. For extracting nested data, I'd just write a custom query using XMLTABLE and not APEX_DATA_PARSER

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. If you can post it as an answer I'll mark it as acepted.

Comment: No worries, just glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to parse the file and able to show it in APEX by using XMLTYPE, upon @Koen's point.

I probably messed the query while I was trying to adapt it to the sample XML above, but the idea is the same. Here is what I did:

```
select *
from 
    my_table x,
    xmltable('Document/group_1'
    passing x.xml_file
    columns 
        MsgId varchar2(20) path 'group_1_1',
        CreDtTm varchar2(50) path 'group_1_1',
        PgNb varchar2(20) path 'group_1_1/MsgPgntn',
        bal xmltype path 'group_1_2/Bal'
        ) y,
    xmltable('/.'
    passing y.bal
    columns 
        cdorprtry varchar2(20) path 'group_1_2/Bal/Tp')z
```

In order to get nested nodes' content in the same row, I had to join each parent node as another XMLTYPE that has repeating TAGs within. In this sample it was "group_1_2/Bal"